# How to view line comments in GitHub?

Tags: github, pull-request

I spent all morning in GitHub reviewing a pull request, writing detailed comments on many lines in the `Diff` view on the pull-request page.

I individually saved every line-by-line comment, and they all appeared in their correct places. I left the pull-request page, and when I returned to it, all my line-by-line comments were gone!

I have no idea why they disappeared, where they went, whether other users can see them and I can't, what any of this means, and whether I can trust myself going forward using GitHub, or whether I just have to go back to the telephone and fax for remote collaboration!

I did some web searches such as "how to view line comments in GitHub" for info about this, but could not find anything to relieve my panic. I will be grateful for advice and clues.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The line-comments depend on the commit that were made on.

If the person that made the pull request rebased that commit then you're not looking at what you were previously looking. It's a different commit, thus there are no comments.

Look on the '[Your Actions](https://github.com/dashboard/yours)' tab and find a line in the actions' history were you commented on that commit, click that commit and you'll see the comments are still there.
If the commit was rebased, you wont find that commit were it used to be (some branch) and not on any repo probably (if it's not on another branch). It is just cached by git and github, until the garbage collector kicks in.

Comment: I'm not seeing the "your actions" tab.  I looked all around the 'pull request' page, then around many other pages.  I ^F searched for it on the page with the browser text search.  I just don't see it!  Still stuck :(

Comment: heh, it's on your dashboard, on top [pic](http://i.imgur.com/0RgoJ.png), here's a [link](https://github.com/dashboard/yours)

Comment: No actions as of 2014

Comment: I just checked, and there is a tab on the dashboard that says "Public Activity." I can see my comments from there. I'm not sure if the "Your Actions" tab exists anymore.

Comment: This may be part of the reason you can't see some of your comments when you need to: https://github.com/orgs/community/discussions/23138 Unfortunately, GitHub seems to see this as a feature, not a bug. It's clearly a bug

Answer (score 41):

This is top result for "Can't view github comments" in google.

If you're here because you've left comments, and can see your own comments, but others *cannnot*, then check for a yellow `pending` label on your comments. Others cannot see your comment until you've completed the review process and selected whether you want to request changes. Once you click through a full review, then others will see your comments.

Note: I'm answering a slightly different question than the O.P., but I have a feeling that lots of other devs with this issue are hitting this stackoverflow question. I'm just hoping to help them. I myself had this issue and couldn't find a more relevant answer than this thread. :)

Comment: This saved me a lot of headaches! Thank you.

Comment: This is the correct answer, still in 2021. UI may not be their strongest. Go in to "Files changed" and then click the green button "Review changes". Then submit. Now you have done a review.

Comment: You must be old like me and losing track of the years @Rbbn - it's 2022 already haha

Comment: yeah you are right on both points @lance.dolan

Comment: Even if you do everything right, your comments may not be visible in-line in the code when you need them to be. If you change the line upon which the comment was originally made in a previous commit, it won't show up in later commits or even in the "all commits" view. Sadly, GitHub considers this a feature: https://github.com/orgs/community/discussions/23138

Answer (score 0):

The old answer doesn't work for me because I don't see Your Actions or Public Actions now.

My pending comments disappeared after I started typing into what I thought was a comment I'd opened for editing. It wasn't open, and one of my keys may have been a shortcut. I could still see the button to finish my review (including the count of my pending comments) but the comments had disappeared.

I eventually got them back by navigating to the pull request, then to the commit I was reviewing.